# Segmentation Fault ao inicializar o Code Blocks no Fedora

Tags: c, c++, codeblocks

Erro apresentado:

> Try to migrate conf-folder
>
> The places where the configuration files and user-data files are
>   stored have been changed to be more standard-conform.
>
> Now moving "/root/.codeblocks/share/codeblocks" to
>   "/root/.local/share/codeblocks" and "/root/.codeblocks" to
>   "/root/.config/codeblocks".

Não estou conseguindo instalar o codeblocks para um projeto da faculdade, o seguinte erro apresentado acima no final da instalação.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O erro apresentado ao executar o sistema.

Comment: Isso é um bug no próprio programa. Só deus sabe o que pode estar causando isso. Só pra constar, não precisa ser o Code::Blocks para programar em C. Até mesmo um editor de texto resolve seu problema-- o importante é ter um compilador. Caso prefira uma IDE (eu também prefiro), tem o NetBeans e o Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Para mim estava dando esse mesmo erro no Fedora 24 usando o repositório oficial do Fedora, usei o repositório do CodeBlocks, que tem sempre a versão mais atual e passou a funcionar. Siga o roteiro abaixo para ser feliz:

1 - Baixe o arquivo [jenslody-codeblocks-fedora-24.repo](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/jenslody/codeblocks/repo/fedora-24/jenslody-codeblocks-fedora-24.repo) ;
2 - Como root, copie o arquivo baixado para pasta /etc/yum.repos.d/ ;
3 - Ainda como root, execute "dnf update codeblocks" ;
4 - Confirme a importação da chave pública do repositório da CodeBlocks.